# Add diagonal of 2 dimensional array in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given: 2 dimensional array :

```
 [[1 2 3]  
  [4 5 6]  
  [9 8 9 ]]
```

Need to add diagonal of the array : 1+5+9 = 15

```
   NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,nil],
                        [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@4,@5,@6,nil],
                        [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@9,@8,@9,nil],nil];

   NSNumber* total = 0;
   for (NSNumber* row in array) {
     total = total + array[row][row];
   }

   NSLog(@"%@",total);
```

Here I can't access the element of the array. It gives error on "array[row][row]". What is the best way to initialize a 2D array and access the element of the array in Objective-C?

Comment: NSUInteger total = 0; for (NSUInteger i = 0, i < array.count; i ++) { total = total + [array[i][i] integerValue];} NSNumber *totalNumer = @(total);  NSLog(@"%@",total); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, what you are doing here: `for (NSNumber* row in array)` is putting each element of `array`, inside the `row` variable (this is called [array enumeration](https://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-loop-through-every-element-in-an-nsarray/) btw).

What you need is to use the **index** of the array - not the **value** of each element (that's what you are doing above).

Also, you don't have to use an object (`NSNumber *`) for your calculations. A simple NSInteger will do.

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,nil],
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@4,@5,@6,nil],
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@9,@8,@9,nil],nil];

NSInteger total = 0;
for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < array.count; row ++) {
    total = total + [array[row][row] integerValue]; // integerValue converts the NSNumber to an NSInteger
}

NSLog(@"%d",total);
```